# What do we call the argument (variable or its value) of a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, argument-passing

OK lets take an example:

```
function student(name,age){
document.write("I am " + name + "and I am " + age + " years old." );
}
var student_name = "Divyansh";
var student_age = 17;
student(student_name,student_age);
```

// now my question is what do we call the arguments of the function student :

(a) is it the variable: student_name & student_age respectively,

(b) or is it the value contained by the variables: divyansh & 17 respectively

PS- I have also posted the same question on codechef, but it seems nobody is interested in giving answer to my stupid and childish question. But, what do i do i am trying to study Javascript myself by the book head first javascript programming and got strucked due to this doubt in one of the question, Please Help.

Comment: a variable is value container(in your case, because your vars doesn't contains object reference), so ==> b for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to know whether you should say

> I called `student` with `student_name` and `student_age`.

or

> I called `student` with `"Divyansh"` and `17`.

right?

Well, that depends on the whole context, and sometimes it's possible to use both.
And this is to some extent a question of opinion, but I'll try to justify my opinion as good as I can.

I believe you should refer to the arguments by their names (i.e. `student_name` and `student_age` if

- their value is of no significance for what you're saying.
  Unnecessary information usually leads to confusion.
- their value is unknown.
- their value is long and you previously mentioned it.
  Long values such as `Math.pow((5*x+7*y-35*v*x*z)/(42*m/35*k+47*f+99*l), 35*22*88*k)` tend to make written text messy and are really annoying to speak out many times in a row, so you'll want to refer to them by name.

You should refer to the arguments by their value when their value matters, e.g. when you have a bug that only occurs when certain values are passed to your function, but not some others.

Now there is a gap between those, where I believe you can use both.
For that case, I'd apply the golden rule
**As short as possible, but as long as required**.

If you had the following code:

```
var name = "Divyansh";
console.log(name);
var name = "Marc";
console.log(name);
var name = "Jon Skeet";
console.log(name);
```

Then I believe all of the following statements are perfectly valid:

> I called `console.log` three times with `name` as argument.

or

> I called `console.log` three times with `"Divyansh"`, `"Marc"` and `"Jon Skeet"` as argument.

But it really depends on how much information you need or want to give.

Answer (score 0):

An argument of a function is an expression with which the function is called.

In this case, the function is called with two expressions as arguments: student_name and student_age.
These expressions yield a value when evaluated: the value of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The function is called with two parameters. These parameters are the **variables**. And the function get the **values of those variables** and assign it in its local variable namely 'name' and 'age'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used console.log() method? Have you ever wondered what's the maximum number of parameters it takes? Answer is as many as it can.

Lets take an example.

```
function print(x,y){
  console.log(x);
  console.log(y);
}
```

Well this is an easy function, takes 2 arguments and print them in the console.

Lets say I have 5 parameters passed to function print. a,b,c,d,e. How would you modify the print method? May be something like this. (Don't write programs like this. It ain't effective).

```
function print(a,b,c,d,e){
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
  console.log(e);
}
```

How about if I pass 100 parameters like, a1, a2, ... a100. What if I pass 1000 parameters. You can't write 1000 console.log statements to print them. So you would think of a for loop to print all the parameters.

But wait!

How do I access all the parameters inside a for loop unless if they are an array (*use for-loop or for-in to iterate*) or an object (*use for-in to iterate*)?

Now comes the object "arguments". This is a built-in object implicitly created by javascript for every function you declare.

What does this store? It stores all the parameters you passed to the function in the form of object.

arguments {
0: a, 
1: b,
2: c,
3: d,
4: e
};

Now I have something like an object that holds all the parameters passed to the function, it will be easier to access them in a for-in loop. Now my print method will look like:

```
function print(a,b,c,d,e,f) {
  for (var prop in arguments) {
    console.log(arguments[prop]);
  }
}
```

This will loop through all the properties of the arguments object and prints the value stored in each property.

What is stored in each property of argument object?

### fn parameter    object-property   value stored in property

```
a                  0             value of parameter a
b                  1             value of parameter b
c                  2             value of parameter c
d                  3             value of parameter d
e                  4             value of parameter e
f                  5             value of parameter f
```

Comment: You explain what the built-in `arguments` variable is and how to use it, but I don't think the question is about that.

Comment: @siguza What do you think the question is?

Comment: Well, see the first couple of lines from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30166714/2302862). But OP's phrasing is really ambiguous apparently.

Answer (score -2):

In your case you are passing two arguments named student_name and student_age to student function which contains value Divyansh and 17 respectively.

Comment: Who downvoted?? at least have the courtesy to tell the reason

Comment: I downvoted because this does not tell the OP anything he doesn't already know.

Comment: @Siguza, With due respect Have you asked him or you are on your own guesses??

Comment: My own guess, but the fact that he knows the difference between `student_age` and `17` lead me to that conclusion.